# Any way I can set quantity limit on woocommerce for Wordpress for each attribute (not variation)

Tags: php, wordpress

Basically I’m selling event tickets, that has the customer choose the date they want to attend as well as the colour of water bottle they want. I want to limit the amount of tickets I send for each date. (But it shouldn’t depend on the water bottle colour). Like 100 tickets max for day 1 and 100 tickets max for day 2 if that makes sense

Alright here it goes

I have an event that I am selling tickets for, using woocommerce
Before a customer can add product to cart they need to select from two drop down menus, 1 for colour of water bottle, and 2nd menu is for selecting the date of event (it’s a 2 day event, and customers can pay for either one or the other)
I created attributes for the colour of water bottle and for the date of the event
I then created variations for them under the variation tab.
Both events should only sell a maximum of 100 tickets.
How can I set a limit of 100 tickets for the 2 event dates each?
It’s challenging because when I set a stock quantity for the date under variations, it also impacts the colour of the water bottle
Example:

Red - day 1 Blue - day 1 Green - day 1

Red -day 2 Blue - day 2 Green - day 2

If I set the quantity limit for each variation to be 100, that means that it’ll actually be able to sell 300 tickets for each event since a customer can simply choose another colour of water bottle.

Does that make more sense?

`your text`

```
// Add filter to manage stock quantity for date variations on product #6239
add_filter('woocommerce_variation_sale_price', 'custom_manage_date_stock_quantity_product_6239', 10, 3 );
add_filter('woocommerce_variation_price', 'custom_manage_date_stock_quantity_product_6239', 10, 3 );
add_filter('woocommerce_product_variation_get_regular_price', 'custom_manage_date_stock_quantity_product_6239', 10, 3 );
add_filter('woocommerce_product_variation_get_sale_price', 'custom_manage_date_stock_quantity_product_6239', 10, 3 );
function custom_manage_date_stock_quantity_product_6239( $price, $variation, $product ) {
    // Check if the variation belongs to product #6239
    if ( $product->get_id() === 6239 ) {
        $date_attribute = $variation['attributes']['Date']; // Replace 'attribute_date' with the actual slug of the Date attribute

        // Set stock quantity based on the date attribute
        switch ( $date_attribute ) {
            case 'Saturday':
                $stock_quantity = 100; // Set the stock limit for this specific date
                break;
            case 'Sunday':
                $stock_quantity = 100;
                break;
            // Add more cases for other date options and their respective stock limits
            default:
                $stock_quantity = 0; // No stock for other date options
        }

        // Apply the stock quantity only for Date variations
        if ( isset($variation['attributes']['Date']) ) {
            $variation['max_qty'] = $stock_quantity;
            $variation['stock_quantity'] = $stock_quantity;
        }
    }

    return $price;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this is the right approach, if the color of the bottle doesn't need to change the price nor quantity, I would consider adding the color of the bottle outside the variations as some custom select box like in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63696902/3909231) (for example)